# Issue in .htaccess file and connecting to db

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I am moving my php work from one laptop to another. And for my work on my local machine I am using WAMP server. So my projects are in c:\wamp\www\

I am facing two problem:

1. One on my project in c:\wamp\www\Test\edge file. So I copied this "Test" file and pasted it on my new laptop. And now when I am trying to access the file using the browser "localhost/Test" it does not shows me the "edge" folder in it. 
   So, I thought probably there is something wrong with the some file inside "edge" folder, and after a few hit and tries I found out the problem was in .htaccess file inside the edge folder. So, I deleted it, and then the localhost/Test shows edge folder in it as well. 
   But now the project is not running properly.

The .htaccess code is given below:

```
  RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^demo+[\/]*$ /demo/

RewriteRule ^service/([a-zA-Z]{1,})+[\/]*$ site/service.php?mode=$1 [QSA,L]
```

2.
 Also I created the same database with the same tables on my new laptop as well, but I still don't know how to connect the database to my website. I mean, do I need to change something in any conf file or what...

Please help me in both the issues.

Regards
Zeeshan

Comment: You should share your original .htaccess file

Comment: I have provided the code in the .htaccess file

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `it does not shows me the "edge" folder in it`? Can you open `localhost/Test/edge/` in browser?

Answer (score 0):

1) what does the localhost/Test show. What is in your .htaccess file?

2) Are the passwords for your laptop / desktop dbs the same?

Comment: The localhost/Test show all the files and folders, except the folder "edge" which has the project in it and also the .htaccess file. But if the .htaccess file is removed, it shows the "edge" folder as well.